# Localization in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, localization, localizable.strings

I'm trying to localize my App. But something is going wrong, and instead of displaying the content of my .string files. It is displaying just a key that I set in the NSLocalizedString. This is example:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.passwordTextField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Password", nil);
}
```

In my Localizations(English) I did:
"Password" = "Password";
In my Localization(Russian) I did:
"Password" = "Пароль";

I checked the directories, I had ru.lproj and en.lproj. But anyway, it didn't work.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, 
Did you add the Langage in the Project -> info tab -> Localizations ?

Comment: Yep! Currently is showing me 2 Files Localized in English and Russian. It is Localizations.string and InfoPlist.strings

Comment: you mean `Localizable.string` and **not** _Localization.string_, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This style has always served me well...

```
NSString *text = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"text-key", currentLocale, @"");
```

The locale must match the filename however.  Such as: "en_US.strings"

Answer (score 4):

The most common reason developers see the English rather than the translation is not naming the localization file properly. It HAS to be **Localizable.strings**  -- spelled exactly that way and no other.

Nothing else works! Also, make sure it is in the properly named directory (en.lproj, ru.lproj, etc.)

There is a complete tutorial [here](http://www.ibabbleon.com/iphone_app_localization.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is too little information and it seems good...
Please, see [this step-by-step tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial) to check what is wrong on your settings (It takes only about 15 minits...)